# Re-crawl pages based on pubDate/lastBuildDate in RSS feed

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I'm setting up a websearch based on Stormcrawler (v1.13) and Elasticsearch. I have configured Stormcrawler to re-crawl indexed pages every 24 hours. Additionally, the website has an RSS feed with recently published or updated pages which is crawled every 10 minute. This works well for detecting new pages. However I would also like to re-crawl the pages that have changed (eg. when a title has changed) within a short amount of time.

When the RSS feed is parsed, the discovered URLs are sent to the scheduler with the status `DISCOVERED` and some extra metadata from the RSS feed (ie. `feed.publishedDate`).

My initial idea was to add a metadata `indexedDate` to the `status` index whenever a document was marked as `FETCHED` (using a custom indexer bolt). This would be the timestamp of the last time the page was indexed. Then I would implement a custom scheduler which checks whether `feed.publishedDate` (from the `DISCOVERED` entry in the RSS-feed) is newer than the `indexedDate` of the corresponding entry that is already stored in the `status` index. If so it would set next fetch date to be the current time so it would be re-fetched ASAP.

The problem with this is that I can't find a good way to access both the indexed page and the discovered RSS-entry, so I can compare the dates. Is there a different recommended way I can acheive what I want?

Here's some of the code from my `crawler.flux`-file:

```
...

bolts:

...

  - id: "feed"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.FeedParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1

...

streams:
  - from: "spout"
    to: "partitioner"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE

  - from: "spout"
    to: "status_metrics"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE     

  - from: "partitioner"
    to: "fetcher"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["key"]

  - from: "fetcher"
    to: "sitemap"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "sitemap"
    to: "feed"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "feed"
    to: "parse"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "parse"
    to: "index"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question, thanks for asking it!

What about having a custom URL filter which checks whether a URL already has an indexed date lesser than the published date and if so changes its status to FETCHED? This way the document will overwrite the existing one in ES and won't be discarded by the cache in the status updater bolt.

You could give it *scheduler.delay.mins=0* in its metadata so that the scheduler sets its value to now.

The downside is that you might need to batch the queries to ES and this would introduce some latency.

Another approach would be to write your own status updater bolt, not use any caching, and write [upserts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts) to ES so that the next fetch date gets modified if necessary. This would probably require a script.

What do you think?

Comment: Many thanks for your input, Julien! Regarding your first suggestion: the URL filter runs for each URL found in the RSS feed, but I can only access the metadata from the feed itself (through `sourceMetadata`) - not the metadata for each RSS entry (which is extracted by `FeedParserBolt`) where the `feed.publishedDate` would be. Or did i misunderstand something?

I guess the second approach could work, although it feels a bit bad to disable the caching :/

Comment: you are absolutely right, sorry about the confusion. You could implement it by adding a custom bolt on the status stream just before the status updater bolt.